# EditItem in ListView - doesn't load edit template

Tags: c#, asp.net

Howdy,
I don't know if it is a known issue - but when I click on the Edit button once - the server reloads the listview - when I click on the edit button once again I receive the EditTemplate and I'm able to edit the list view ... is this is a known behaviour?

Furthermore: The c# behind is working through the full editing cycle ( loads the special editing data ) - but I still only see the usual "view".

//Added some meat to the question

```
public void test_ItemEditing(Object sender, ListViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    // returns the current key
    DataKey currentDataKey = speiseplanListView.DataKeys[e.NewEditIndex];

    // fetches the information - for the whole plane
    DataTable speiseplan = getSpeiseplan(0);
    DataTable preisgruppen = getPreisgruppen();

    extractTags(speiseplan);
    extractPreise(speiseplan, preisgruppen);
    speiseplanListView.DataSource = speiseplan;
    speiseplanListView.DataBind();
}
```

This is the edit function - which gets called once the user presses the "edit" button --- it's completed on both tries .. however only the second try returns the "EditItemTemplate".

The page_load function is rather unnecessary for the edit event - since the edit event is a postback event - so the page load gets skipped in both cases.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["USERID"] == null)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
        Session.Abandon();
    }
    else
    {
        this.kantinenID = Convert.ToInt32(Request["id"]);
        this.userID = Convert.ToInt16(Session["USERID"]);
        if (IsPostBack == false)
        {
            try
            {
                switch (Request["action"])
                {
                     ...                  
                }
            }
            catch (System.FormatException ex)
            {
              ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this sounds to me, like a page lifeCycle problem... Do you bind your listView Data on every pageRequest? can you show some code pls

Comment: please add some code to your question

Comment: The page is rather large, so which parts of the code do you want to see?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the start of your ItemEditing handler:

```
speiseplanListView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
```

Also, verify that speiseplanListView.DataBind(); is not being called upon postback in your page load handler.

Finally, [this tutorial](http://geekswithblogs.net/rashid/archive/2007/09/13/Asp.net-List---Data-Editing.aspx) may be of some value to you